# in app purchase in macOS application an unknown error ocurred

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase, macos-sierra

I've implemented in app purchases in my macOS app, however every time when I try to test it with my sandbox user I've got "unknown error".[image]

Then in `updatedTransactions` callback method transaction is failed.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Another forum post describing similar issues suggested deleting `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist`. I backed that file up, deleted it, and restarted. I can now log in and out of AppStore, access all of my AppStore purchased apps, and it 'sticks' across shutdowns and restarts.

Process is pretty simple, I'll spell it out for future reference:

1. Open Terminal
2. `cd /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`
3. `cp NetworkInterfaces.plist ~/NetworkInterfaces.plist.bak` - Make a hasty backup in your home directory
4. `sudo rm NetworkInterfaces.plist` delete the original
5. Restart your Mac
6. Open AppStore and try to sign in. It should work.

Apparently this works because the MAC address is used as part of the receipt/authorization process.

Comment: just tried, but it doesn't work for me. I have the same error as before